# Passing an Array to a SQL query using Java's PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I've been having a little trouble passing an array into a SQL query using Java's prepared statements. I had first tried the sourceforge driver, however I would get the AbstractMethodError when I call setArray method. Not knowing the solution to that I swapped to the Microsoft sqlserver driver, but now I get a different error entirely, which is "java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: This operation is not supported." Tried a whole bunch of things to try and resolve this but nothing appears to work.

My Java code looks similar to examples I've seen here and on the internet, and is as follows,

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
String[] suppliers = {"21","2774","120563","3714","59"};
ps.setArray(1, connection.createArrayOf("text", suppliers));
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Example of my SQL queries. The only line of real interest is the line before last where I have added the '?' character, which as I understand it is how I pass a parameter to a SQL Query.

```
productsPrices.query = select contract.supplierid as 'hotelid' \
  , round((rate.s1/money.buy)*euro.sell,0) as "single" \
  , round((rate.s2/money.buy)*euro.sell,0) as "double" \
  ,service.Name as 'roomtype' \
  ,stock.alloc - stock.taken as 'stock.available' \
  , contract.notes as 'boardType' \
  , object.name as 'occupancy' \
  ,object.cap as 'capacity' \
  ,object.mincap as 'min capacity' \
  ,stock.date as 'date' \
from stock stock \
  inner join rate rate on stock.rateid = rate.id \
  inner join contract contract on rate.contractid = contract.id \
  inner join service service on contract.serviceid = service.ID \
  inner join object object on service.objectid = object.ID \
  inner join band band on contract.termsid = band.ID \
  inner join Money money on band.moneyid = money.id \
  inner join Money euro on euro.Name  = 'Euros' \
where stock.date > getdate() \
and stock.closed = 0 \
and (stock.alloc - stock.taken) > 0 \
and stock.date > getdate() \
      and contract.supplierid in (?) \
      and contract.Finish > GETDATE()
```

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Web Edition (64-bit) version 10.50.1600.1 :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved same issue by dynamically generating string with required number of question marks.
Here's a snippet:-

```
String param = "(";
for(int i=0;i<suppliers.length;i++){
param = param+"?,";
}
param = param.substring(0,param.length()-1);
param=param+")";

query = query + param;

PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);

for(int i=0;i<suppliers.length;i++){
ps.setString(i+1,suppliers[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. I will try this in a little bit when I get home. :)